# Find directions in which f increases and decreases the most rapidly. Then find the derivatives of f at these directions.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

$f(x,y)=3x^2+2xy+4y^2$

This is what I have to find:

**direction of fastest increase**

I found the gradient vector:

$f(x,y)=(6x+2y)i+(2x+8y)j$

$f(9,2) = \langle 58,34\rangle$

Is this the direction of fastest increase? Or is it $\frac{58}{2\sqrt{1130}}$i,$\frac{34}{2\sqrt{1130}}$j

**direction of fastest decrease**

Is this the direction of fastest increase?$\frac{-58}{2\sqrt{1130}}$i,$\frac{-34}{2\sqrt{1130}}$j

**derivative in direction of fastest increase**

I know this the dot product but I dont know what vectors to use.

**derivative in direction of fastest decrease**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direction of fastest increase is in the same direction of the gradient vector at that point. If you think about it geometrically, you'll know that the $\nabla F$ at a point is perpendicular to the level surface/contour path. So it is correct that $\nabla$ also indicates that direction. The direction of the fastest decrease is just $-\nabla$ at $P$.

For the second part of you question use the formula of Directional Derivatives where $$D_u f(x,y)= f_x(x,y)a+f_y(x,a)b$$ where $<a,b>$ is the unit vector of your direction.

So that means $$D_u f(x,y)= (6x+2y)\frac{58}{2 \sqrt{1130}}+(2x+8y)\frac{34}{2 \sqrt{1130}}$$

You can substitute your Point in for $x$ and $y$ and solve. You should get $$58(\frac {58} {2\sqrt{1130}}) + 34(\frac {34} {2\sqrt{1130}})$$

Similarly you use the same method to determine the derivative in the direction of the fastest decrease.

NB: you can only substitute a point in for $x$, and $y$ if the question specifically states that it only needs to be calculated at that point. If not, the general solution (leaving it in $x$ and $y$) has to be used as that would give the derivative of greatest increase/decrease for all points.

Comment: ok so the direction of fastest increase is <58,34>? so then what is the derivative of the direction? @DividedUniverse

Comment: Have a look here http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/DirectionalDeriv.aspx He gives very helpful advice regarding your problem.

Comment: and also the direction of fastest decrease is <-58,-34>??

Comment: @Layla yes, think of $\nabla$ pointing up a hill (if that makes sense). Then the fastest decrease is just in the opposite direction (i.e. the negative of the gradient).

Comment: thanks i read the link, but the examples already give a direction. so what am i supposed to do? do the dot product of <58,34> and $\frac{58}{2sqrt(1130)}$?

Comment: @Layla just to clarify, how did you calculate $\frac{58}{2sqrt(1130)}
$?

Comment: sorry I meant the dot product of <58,34> and <$\frac{58}{2sqrt(1130)}$,$\frac{34}{2sqrt(1130)}$> i got that part by making it a unit vector. please explain to me how to do this problem.

Comment: @Layla Thanks! If you just want the direction of fastest increase/decrease it does not matter if it is a unit vector or not. For the second part of your question you need to calculate the Directional Derivative in the direction of your gradient or negative gradient. For this part you need the unit vector. I hope that helps.

Comment: yes i know i need to calculate the direction derivative of the direction of my gradient. so what do i do with the unit vector??? do the dot product???

Comment: please tell me if im correct. so i do 58(58/2sqrt(1130)) + 34(34/2sqrt(1130))????

Comment: @Layla yes that is correct

Comment: @Layla I have edited my answer to reflect what was written here in the comment section and to add more detail.